# jQuery parallax navigation doesn't scroll to target

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, scrolltop

I have put together a parallax scrolling demo but I'm having problem to navigate in-between contents.

- `Header` and `Footer` are fixed and all the rest isn't.
- On the variables `section3Top` `section4Top` I guess height isn't calculated properly.

I can't see the issue.

Please have a look my demo and try click through the menu. It should work by clicking the menu, also on scroll and on resize.

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Zza7t/

JS:

```
function redrawDotNav(){
    var section1Top =  0;
    var section2Top =  $('#BuyKeep').offset().top - (($('#Rentals').offset().top - $('#BuyKeep').offset().top) / 2);
    var section3Top =  $('#Rentals').offset().top - (($('#WaystoWatch').offset().top - $('#Rentals').offset().top) / 2);
    var section4Top =  $('#WaystoWatch').offset().top - (($(document).height() - $('#WaystoWatch').offset().top) / 2);

    $('nav#primary a').removeClass('active');

    if($(document).scrollTop() >= section1Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section2Top){
        $('nav#primary a.about').addClass('active');
    } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section2Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section3Top){
        $('nav#primary a.BuyKeep').addClass('active');
    } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section3Top && $(document).scrollTop() < section4Top){
        $('nav#primary a.Rentals').addClass('active');
    } else if ($(document).scrollTop() >= section4Top){
        $('nav#primary a.WaystoWatch').addClass('active');
    }
}

function scrollFooter(scrollY, heightFooter) {

    if(scrollY >= heightFooter) {
      $('#WaystoWatch').css({
          'bottom' : '0px'
      });
    }
    else {
      $('#WaystoWatch').css({
          'bottom' : '-' + heightFooter + 'px'
      });
    }
}

    function heightsCalculator(){
        var windowHeight    = $(window).height(),
        footerHeight    = $('#WaystoWatch').height(),
        heightDocument  = (windowHeight) + ($('#BuyKeep').height()) + ($('#Rentals').height()) + ($('#WaystoWatch').height()) - 0;

        $('#scroll-animate, #scroll-animate-main').css({
            'height' :  heightDocument + 'px'
        }); 
        $('#about').css({
            'height' : windowHeight + 'px'
        });
        $('.wrapper-parallax').css({
            'margin-top' : windowHeight + 'px'
        });

        scrollFooter(window.scrollY, footerHeight);

        window.onscroll = function(){
        var scroll = window.scrollY;

        $('#scroll-animate-main').css({
            'top' : '-' + scroll + 'px'
        });

        $('#about').css({
            'background-position-y' : 50 - (scroll * 100 / heightDocument) + '%'
        });

        scrollFooter(scroll, footerHeight);

        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only link that isn't working for me is the "footer".. Because you have it position fixed it is going to change its offset as you scroll up and down the page. You want to do the same thing you did with your header and scroll a specific location of the page, in this case the bottom. There is also something re-sizing your "footer" height and I am not able to locate where you are doing this or why, but I am assuming it isn't necessary.

```
$('a.WaystoWatch').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$('body').height()
    }, 1000, function() {
        parallaxScroll(); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Zza7t/2/)